# Why do my ethers.js transactions keep pending/dropping on polygon even with a lot of gas added?

Tags: blockchain, polygon, ethers.js, matic

I'm trying to automate sending transactions through ethers.js. It works all perfectly on Rinkeby, but then on Polygon the transactions stay pending for days even when adding much more gas than neccessary.

Pending tx:
https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x1d7a88c38b190526729ab43eeac2b5330f18c0ee42707477ac64fc4d4d45d29c

Using the functions directly on polygonscan work, and sometimes randomly some transactions will go through as well, so it's not all wrong but most txs will fail.

What is the issue here?

```
let tx = await contract.airdrop(addr_, tokenID_, amount_, { 
    type: 2,
    maxFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits("500", "gwei"), 
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: ethers.utils.parseUnits("500", "gwei"), 
    gasLimit: 20000000
});
```